# How to implement breakpoint continuation when multiple fetch API work at the same time

Tags: javascript, download, es6-promise, fetch-api, http-range

I need to request a large file in pieces and construct a new readablestream from the response.

At first, I only requested one piece of data at a time, and on this basis, I realized the breakpoint continuation to deal with the instability of the network

```
let _this = this
let responseList = []
let response = null
let reader = null
let offset = 0
let start = 0
let end = start + this.RANGE_SIZE
return new ReadableStream({
  async start(controller) {
    responseList.push(await fetch(_this.url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: {range: `bytes=${start}-${end}`}}))
    reader = responseList[0].body.getReader()
  },
  async pull(controller) {
    try {
      var {done, value} = await reader.read()
    } catch (e) {
      let errorOffset = 0
      responseList[0] = await fetch(_this.url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: {range: `bytes=${start}-${end}`}})
      reader = responseList[0].body.getReader()
      while (true) {
        let {done, value} = await reader.read()
        if (errorOffset + value.length > offset){
          value = value.slice(offset - errorOffset)
          controller.enqueue(value)
          return
        }else {
          errorOffset += value.length
        }
      }
    }

    if (done) {
      offset = 0
      start = end + 1
      end += _this.RANGE_SIZE
      responseList.shift()

      responseList.push(await fetch(_this.url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: {range: `bytes=${start}-${end}`}}))
      reader = responseList[0].body.getReader()
      const {done, value} = await reader.read()
      controller.enqueue(value)
      offset += value.length
    } else {
      controller.enqueue(value)
      offset += value.length
    }
  }
})
```

But now I want to download two slices at the same time to improve the download efficiency.

```
  async start(controller) {
    responseList.push(await fetch(_this.url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: {range: `bytes=${start}-${end}`}}))
    start = end + 1
    end += _this.RANGE_SIZE
    responseList.push(await fetch(_this.url, {responseType: 'blob', headers: {range: `bytes=${start}-${end}`}}))
    reader = responseList[0].body.getReader()
  },
```

In this case, I cannot get whether the second reader has failed. try...catch... not work.

Is there a way to solve this problem

Comment: What do you mean by "*reader has failed*"? `.body.getReader()` can't fail I think.

Comment: You are right. I don't judge whether the fetch fail through .body.getReader(), but reader.read().  This is no problem when there is only one fetch request, but now there are two fetch requests. The second fetch will not execute the reader.read() function until the first set of data is read.

Comment: Is there any other way to judge whether the fetch API fail ?

Comment: So what failure exactly are you trying to handle?

Comment: Just need to judge whether the fetch fail